# How do I define interface property that is constrained by enum?

Tags: typescript

Assuming I need to define the shape of an object, like:

```
const orange = {
   color: 'red',
   sweet: true,
   acidic: true,
   bitter: false
}
```

With the `interface`

```
interface Fruit {
   color: string,
   ?
}
```

Where unknown part (flavors) should be constrained (only below keys are allowed, not necessarily all of them) by the following `enum`:

```
enum Taste {
   ACIDIC = 'acidic',
   SWEET = 'sweet',
   BITTER = 'bitter'
}
```

With corresponding values of boolean type.

I could've defined some `Record<Taste, boolean>`, but how do I *incorporate* that into my target `Fruit` interface, when (to make things even more complicated) I cannot define `Fruit` as a type (instead of interface), since it extends `Food` interface?

Comment: Why not to include the flavors into the `Fruit` interface?

Comment: @DorinBaba : consider I'm using flavors separately but still want to keep those 2 in sync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript interfaces support multiple inheritance

You should be able to do

```
enum Taste {
   ACIDIC = 'acidic',
   SWEET = 'sweet',
   BITTER = 'bitter'
}

interface Food { /* props common to all foods */ } 

interface Fruit extends Food, Record<Taste, boolean> {
    color: string;
}
```

In the event that one of the properties of `Record<Taste, boolean>` conflicts with a property on `Food` (i.e they have incompatible types), TS will give a type error at compile time.

If you don't want to require that all of the `Taste` properties are present, you could have `Fruit` implement `Partial<Record<Taste, boolean>>` instead.